# Partial GET request for Google Calendar html download

Tags: html, get, google-calendar-api

Hi I'm working on an Arduino project and I'd like to display the next event from a Google calendar on a small display.  I want to know if there's a way to limit the size of a HTML request from Google.  Right now when I do the request I'm getting my full calendar's data.  This significantly slows down the time it takes to get the event.  I tried using a GET request and Range bytes 1000-3000 but this doesn't seem to work.  Does anyone know any workarounds for this without going through Oauth?

Answer (score 1):

You want the "maxResults" parameter and you may also like to limit the fields returned using the "fields" parameter as well. Check the [events > list docs](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list) for details.